# Why does the US Senate act so unlike a parliamentary regime when consenting to Cabinet nominations?

Tags: united-states, president, cabinet

In France, the president is elected directly by the people, not by parliament, just as in the US (the electoral college doesn't matter here). In France, the Cabinet ("gouvernement") is responsible before the National Assembly, where it's confirmed by a single vote of confidence (usually), whereas in the US the Cabinet members are individually confirmed by the Senate. In both cases, the Cabinet members are appointed by the president (and by the prime minister in France, but he's himself appointed by the president). Last thing, in France the president has the power to trigger a snap election in the house to which the Cabinet is responsible, a power which the US president does not have over any house.

My question is this. In France, when there's a majority against the president in the National Assembly, the president names a prime minister and Cabinet from the side which won the election, not from his own - this happened three times in the current french republic, and it's called "cohabitation". Yet, in the US, the Senate (almost) always confirms the Cabinet appointees, or in any case don't oppose them by a manner of partisan principle. Even though the president doesn't have the power to punish them by ending their terms early, like the french president does.

Is there a reason for that other than force of habit ? Why is there no cohabitation in the US, where an incoming president has to have Cabinet members of the opposite party because he couldn't flip the Senate ?

PS : please don't mention france's current status with the minority government not getting a confirmation by the AN. As sad and politically problematic as it is, there is no singular majority opposed to Macron that's able to govern, so that's not comparable with the three cohabitations.

Comment: Admittedly, occurrences when the presidency flips but the senate doesn't follow are rare. One such occurence is 1968, where Nixon won the presidency but the Senate stayed democratic. There may be others. But in the general case, there's a habit for the Senate to allow the president to name his secretaries with large freedom, and that's what I'm questioning here.

Comment: The person most responsible for designing the US presidency is [James Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Wilson_%28Founding_Father%29?wprov=sfla1). His speeches and papers should answer the question. [France, at the time, was an absolute monarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XVI?wprov=sfla1).

Comment: Are you asking why POTUS does not appoint the government? It's because of the constitution.

Comment: @BillOnne no, I'm asking why the Cabinet always reflects the presidency, and not the Senate, and why the Senate always allows that.

Comment: This is not the case.  https://www.senate.gov/legislative/NominationsRejectedorWithdrawn.htm

Comment: Also, members of the government and members of cabinet are very different.

Comment: The link you posted shows a tiny amout of rejections compared to the (probably) hundreds of appointments proposed by presidents, a significant number of which were made by the oppostion party in the Senate. That's what my question is about. You seem not to have understood it at all.

Comment: Why is the answer not simply "France is not the USA".  Why would you expect the systems to be the same?   Different countries have different systems.  One might as well ask "Why is the Head of State in France not passed from Parent to Child, like it is in Belgium?"  Answer - because France isn't Belgium. Belgium has a Monarch. France doesn't.  "Why is the US unlike a parliamentary regime of France."  Answer - Because the US isn't France.  The US does not have a Parliamentary system of Government.

Comment: @Gouvernathor part of the answer about appointments is that there is probably a lot of deal making behind the scenes.  The power of the Senate to veto probably also means that Cabinet nominations are usually more moderate, and an opposite party Senate accepts someone they wouldn't have picked but isn't going to try to do anything they strongly disagree with.

Comment: @JamesK the answer for Belgium is that the belgian constitution establishes a hereditary monarchy, and the french one doesn't. The US constitution gives the Senate a power to stonewall the nominations of the opposition party, my question is why they don't use it. Or, if you prefer it that way, "Why is the US not like France in that regard". I'm really surprised how most of you don't understand the question : I *know* the systems are different, that's why I ask what makes them different in *that* regard.

Answer (score 1):

The US uses a presidential system of government. Executive and legislative powers are mostly separate.

Voters in the US elect a Congress which *makes* the laws, and completely separately (through the electoral college) a President who *enforces* the laws. These are considered two separate functions of government in the US system, and it is considered possible and legitimate that voters might elect one person as president to enforce the laws, but a majority of legislators from the opposing party to make the laws. (The president still has some legislative power in the form of the veto; and as you mentioned, the Senate has some executive power by its power to confirm or reject certain government officials.) This means that it is possible that the executive branch might want one thing to happen, and the legislative branch another. This also explains such things as "government shutdowns" occasionally happening in the US.

Meanwhile, in parliamentary systems like France, Germany, UK (they are not all 100% the same, but they share the basic traits), the executive branch derives its power from the legislative branch. The legislative branch is elected, the executive branch (frequently called a prime minister and cabinet) derives its democratic legitimacy from the fact that a majority of legislators support it; it may officially be appointed by a mostly-ceremonial head of state like in Austria or the UK (my understanding is that the French president has somewhat more power, but basically the same thing applies there), or elected by the legislature like in Germany. In any case, the executive depends on the confidence of the legislature, so they generally work in unison, it is rare for them to disagree on anything important.

What are the practical effects of this difference?

In parliamentary systems, most laws (although there are exceptions) are prepared by the executive branch, then sent to the legislature. The legislature may still amend them, but in any case, if the executive branch wants some general policy to be implemented, then that is probably going to happen. The executive branch has a built-in majority in the legislature and can mostly get the laws passed that it wants to pass. There may even be parliamentary rules that prioritize those laws introduced by the executive vis-a-vis those introduced by legislators.

In presidential systems (I am not very familiar with any other than the US, so I am going to mostly write about the US here), laws are made entirely by the legislative branch; the US President only has the ability to veto them in the end (and of course, also to publicly say "if this law contains or does not contain this clause, I am going to veto it", which may have influence on legislators). The executive branch's central job is not to make laws, only enforce them.

Your question was: why does it not generally happen that a Senate controlled by the opposing party forces the President to appoint cabinet members of that opposing party, even though that is somewhat similar to the head of state in parliamentary systems appointing a prime minister and cabinet?

I think the most likely explanation is that **there would simply be no point to it**. In a parliamentary system, the prime minister and cabinet have great legislative power, they basically make most of the decisions regarding where the country will be going. In the US, the cabinet of course also has some power (in making regulations and in deciding on enforcement priorities), but they have no real say in what laws will be passed.

In theory, they *could* completely obstruct the nomination process so that they get exactly those candidates that they want, but if they did that, you could be sure that the talking point (by the President and likely also by the media) would be "Senate obstructs nominations of perfectly qualified candidate". It is not how the system is meant to work. The President is supposed to make most of the decisions on how the executive branch operates, whom he would like to work with; the Senate has some power to scrutinize this, but is not supposed to completely obstruct the process for petty reasons.

Comment: Sure, but having the power to influence laws is far from being the only benefit of controlling who ends up in Cabinet. A massive amount of control over the executive branch is another (not unlimited because the US and french presidents retains some powers, but still) and an actual chance of triggering the 25th amdt is another. So, you're saying that over more than 200 years, the Senate never decided to use that power, just because they thought "it's not how the system is meant to work" ? - which really means "how the founding fathers said it was meant to work" btw...

Comment: Also I doubt the media thing and political backlash would be that damming - just like the nuclear option, it would settle once the opposite party of who used it first, uses it too. That's baffling that no senate majority in 200 years had the guts to do that - even though, again, they have more power to withhold consent than the french AN does.

Comment: @Gouvernathor Congress can have pretty much all the control it wants over the executive branch (subject to some exceptions) by simply *passing a law* that says the executive branch has to act this way or another way. Since it can do that, there is not that much of a point of using obstructions of nominations for that purpose.

Comment: I strongly disagree it's factually the case (due to the mess it is to pass a law in the US, and to the presidential veto among others), but I guess if most of the senators share your opinion, that's an answer to my question.

Comment: Last point (though I don't want to spam), I think the same point about "how the system is meant to work" could be made about the president's power to appoint judges. Yet, since the 2000's, there's a strong use of consent being withheld to judicial appointments. Although your point about there being no real benefit from withholding consent applies less to SCOTUS nominees whose influence is major.